# sqlite3 select query just not working in one device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am trying to build iOS app with `sqlite3` DB, i just test it on iPhone 6 with ios 8.3 and iPhone 5s with ios 8.1 and iPhone 4 with ios 7.1 its work perfectly but when try to test it on another iphone 6 with ios 8.3 app run and DB work but when try to execute following query its not show anything!

```
//this class copy DB if needed and return the Db path.
DBLOADER *test =[[DBLOADER alloc]init];
BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([test.getDBPath UTF8String], &db);
if(openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name,st from department_name where ky='%@' ",_key];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@"sql run");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *field1 =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *field1str =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:field1];
            [DBnamez addObject:field1str];
            NSLog(@"Name----->%@",field1str);

            char *field2 =(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSString *field2str =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:field2];
            [DBstatus addObject:field2str];
            NSLog(@"->%@",field2str);
            NSLog(@"status----->%@",field2str);

        }


        NSLog(@"read Data successfully!!");
        [self.table reloadData];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"cant read data!!!");
    }



}
```

but just nslog print: `cannot read data!!!`

Comment: Reset simulator  or Delete the app and try again

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Reset simulator or Delete the app and try again [jaleel-nazir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177007/jaleel-nazir)